# How to give active class to parent router that contain some extra links in angular?

Tags: angular, angular-router

I have the following code for generating an menu for my demo project. This is create from 3 routers like in this [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dLFC9.png).

```
    <li *ngFor="let item of items"
        class="nav-links__item"
        [ngClass]="{'nav-links__item--with-submenu': item.submenu}"
        [routerLinkActive]="['active-link']"
    >

        <a *ngIf="!(item.link | validUrl) && item.link !=='/'" [routerLink]="item.link | localize">
            <ng-container [ngTemplateOutlet]="link"></ng-container>
        </a>

</li>
```

My problem is that this router link active sets "active-link" class only for items that not have submenu.

For example :
In this [image2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xP6Af.png) and [image3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qyHi4.png) active-link is set for router that don't have submenu.

But when I click to Product router this active-link class is not setting for this router and my border bottom red style is not working.

Answer (score 1):

`[routerLinkActive]` needs the element it is set on, or its child element to have `[routerLink]` set, like in the following example:

```
<div routerLinkActive="active-link" [routerLinkActiveOptions]="{exact: true}">
  <a routerLink="/user/jim">Jim</a>
  <a routerLink="/user/bob">Bob</a>
</div>
```

The above sets the active-link class on the  parent tag when the URL is either '/user/jim' or '/user/bob'.

In your code, make sure that the `[routerLink]` appears always, either on the `<li>` element or on its child-element, regardless of the `*ngIf`.

Comment: Please select the answer as the 'accepted answer' if it helped you.